# Textbox equal to column in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When I select a row in my VB program from my SQL Server table, how can I get my textboxes to reflect the data in the row selected?

Comment: Way too many variables for a reasonable answer.  How are you connecting to the database?  Are you using data binding to some sort of grid?  How are you reading data?

Comment: Connecting to the MSSQL database using a standard Data connection. The data is just shown in a table as it would be in the SQL management console... I don't really know how to explain it really!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the DataGridView control, start with this:

```
DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
DataGridView1.MultiSelect = False
```

Then handle the SelectionChanged event and put values in your textboxes:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
        TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Text1").Value
        TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Text2").Value
        TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Text3").Value
    End Sub
```